# Prolog list elements editing

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, predicate, subtraction

I need to write a predicate that will take a list of numbers and a number X, and then from X elements from this list (staring from the first one) it will subtract 1.
It may seem easy but I am new to this language and I cannot write it properly.

Here is what I got for now:

```
sub([H|T], X):-NEWH is H-1, NEWX is X-1, sub(T, NEWX).
```

but how can I end this reccursion? Like this?

```
sub([H|T], 0).
```

And how to avoid errors when X is larger than the number of elements in list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do four things:

- Add a parameter for the result - your rule manufactures a new list, there needs to be an extra parameter there.
- Add a base case for when `X` is zero - your `sub([H|T], 0).` could be further simplified as `sub(_, 0).` To make sure that you accept negative `X`, you could even make it `sub(_,X) :- X =< 0.`
- Add another base case for when the list is empty - this would let you handle situations when `X` is too large: `sub([], _).`
- Make sure that the recursive clause does not apply when `X` is zero - all you need to do is to add a check `X > 0` to your recursive clause.

Here is how the resultant rules would look:

```
sub(L,X,L) :- X =< 0.
sub([], _,[]).
sub([H|T], X, [NEWH|NEWT]) :- X > 0, NEWH is H-1, NEWX is X-1, sub(T, NEWX, NEWT).
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/rFH2Kg)

> I want to remove zeros from the list

You need to add another clause for that:

```
sub(L,X,L) :- X =< 0.
sub([], _,[]).
sub([H|T], X, [NEWH|NEWT]) :- X > 0, NEWH is H-1, NEWH > 0, NEWX is X-1, sub(T, NEWX, NEWT).
sub([H|T], X, NEWT) :- X > 0, NEWH is H-1, NEWH =< 0, NEWX is X-1, sub(T, NEWX, NEWT).
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/uoSnGE)

Comment: Thank You very much! And one more question - if an element after subtracting 1 equals 0, then I would like to remove it from the list. Where should I add code for this?

Comment: @veronicaxoxo If you want to remove zeros from the list, add a separate clause similar to your recursive clause. Please take a look at the edit.

Comment: Thank You, but shouldn't it return [5,6,8,9] instead [[5,6,7,8,9]]?

[link](http://ideone.com/RIIR6Q)

Comment: @veronicaxoxo You are right, I should have removed the square brackets around `NEWT`.

Comment: BTW: in your ideone links you write  `:- goal_to_be_executed.` which should read `:- initialization(goal_to_be_executed).`

Answer (score 0):

Prolog is declarative. That means that once an object is created, it can't be modified (this is not strictly true for most Prolog systems, but it is in many cases unwise to perform such hacking).

What you thus need is a predicate, that takes as input the first list, and generates a new list. For your example this is for instance:

```
sub([],_,[]). %base case: you reached the end of the list, return an empty list as well
sub(L,0,L).   %base case: you reached zero, no more editing, return the list.
sub([H|T],X,[NewH|newT]) :- %recursive case, subtract one from the head and from X and perform recursion.
    NewH is H-1,
    NewX is X-1,
    sub(T,NewX,newT).
```

Note there are two base cases:

- `sub([],_,[])`: you reached the end of the list, an possibly `X` has not reached zero yet. Then return an empty list as well.
- `sub(L,0,L)`: `X` reached zero, then you stop editing and return the list `L` untoched.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your code doesn't do anything, since your NEWH is not returned anywhere. 
2) Your code should return the full list, with modified elements, so your recursion should stop either by: 
  a) Comparing X to zero and appending the rest of the list 
    or 
  b) Recurring until the end of the list and compare X to 0 everytime.

The first approach is simple:

```
sub(L, 0, L).
sub([H|T], X, [H1 | Res]) :- 
    H1 is H-1,
    X1 is X-1,
    sub(T, X1, Res).
```

Then calling:

```
>>> sub([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 4, L).
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```